# How to check username format with a regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I need to check username format using a regular expression.
My username criterion is:

- Must contain 1 or more letters, anywhere.
- May contain any amount of numbers, anywhere.
- Can contain up to 2 - or _, anywhere.

`^[0-9\-_]*[a-z|A-Z]+[0-9\-_]*$` is what I was using but this will reject usernames such as `123hi123hi`, or `hi123hi`. I need something less string location dependent.

I'm using Ruby on Rails to match strings against this.

A very inefficient Ruby function version for Rails is:

```
validate :check_username
def check_username
  if self.username.count("-") > 2
    errors.add(:username, "cannot contain more than 2 dashes")
  elsif self.username.count("_") > 2
    errors.add(:username, "cannot contain more than 2 underscores")
  elsif self.username.count("a-zA-Z") < 1
    errors.add(:username, "must contain a letter")
  elsif (self.username =~ /^[0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+$/) !=0
    errors.add(:username, "cannot contain special characters")
  end
end
```

Comment: I like your solution. Your distinction in three different cases allows you to return precise error messages, and the code is easy to maintain. I would consider to use the regexp `/[[:alpha:]]/` for checking the letter (which would, for instance, allow the user to use accented letters too - of course this makes only sense if you **want** to allow it). Similarily, you could make the case about special characters more general. See the section on *character classes* in the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html).

Comment: @CarySwoveland The ^ is outside of the [] not inside of it, I think you're misreading it.  It's an inclusion group, not an exclusion group.  The ^ denotes the start of the string.

Comment: I understand that, but yes, my observation was incorrect. `^` is the start of the *line*, however :-)

Comment: "May contain any amount of numbers, anywhere" is not worth testing for, which reduces the problem. Is a username of "a" valid? According to the rules it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches you could use.

**Construct a single regex**

Because regular expressions are concerned with the ordering of characters in a string, one would have to construct a regular expression for each of the following combinations and then "or" those regexes into a single regex.

- one letter, zero hyphens, zero underscores
- one letter, zero hyphens, one underscores
- one letter, zero hyphens, two underscores
- one letter, one hyphen, zero underscores
- one letter, one hyphen, one underscore
- one letter, one hyphen, two underscores
- one letter, two hyphens, zero underscores
- one letter, two hyphens, one underscore
- one letter, two hyphens, two underscores

Digits and additional letters could appear anywhere in the username.

Let's call those regular expressions `t0`, `t1`,..., `t8`. The desired single, overall regular expression would be:

```
/#{t0}|#{t1}|...|#{t8}/
```

Let's consider the construction of `t4` (one letter, one hyphen, one underscore).
Six possible orders are possible for this combination.

- a letter, a hyphen, an underscore
- a letter, an underscore, a hyphen
- a hyphen, a letter, an underscore
- a hyphen, an underscore, a letter
- an underscore, a letter, a hyphen
- an underscore, a hyphen, a letter

We would need to construct a regular expression for each of these six orders  (`r0`, `r1`,..., `r5`) and then "or" them to obtain `t4`:

```
t4 = /#{r0}|#{r1}|#{r2}|#{r3}|#{r4}|#{r5}/
```

Now let's consider the construction of a regex `r0` that would implement the first of these orderings (a letter, a hyphen, an underscore):

```
r0 = /\A[a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*_[a-z0-9]*\z/i

"3ab4-3cd_e5".match?(r0) #=> true
"3ab4-3cde5".match?(r0)  #=> false (no underscore)
"34-3cd_e5".match?(r0)   #=> false (no letter before the hyphen)
"3ab4_3cd-e5".match?(r0) #=> false (underscore precedes hyphen)
```

Construction of each of the other five `ri`'s would be similar.

We would then need to compute `ti` for each of the eight combination other than the fifth one. `t0` (one letter, zero hyphens, zero underscores) is easy:

```
t0 = /\A[a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*\z/i
```

By contrast, `t8` (one letter, two hyphens, two underscores) would be a much longer regex than `t4` (considered above), as a regular expression would have to be hand-crafted for each of `5!/(2!*2!) #=> 30` orderings (`r0`, `r1`,..., `r29`).

It should now be obvious that the use of a single regular expression is simply not the right tool for validating usernames.

**Do not construct a single regex**

```
def username_valid?(username)
  cnt = username.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c,cnt|
    case c
    when /\d/
    when /[[:alpha:]]/
      cnt[:letter] += 1
    when '-'
      cnt[:hyphen] += 1
    when '_'
      cnt[:underscore] += 1
    else
      return false
    end
  end
  cnt.fetch(:letter, 0) > 0 && cnt.fetch(:hyphen, 0) <= 2 &&
    cnt.fetch(:underscore, 0) <= 2
end

username_valid? "Bob"           #=> true 
username_valid? "Bob1_23_-"     #=> true 
username_valid? "z"             #=> true 
username_valid? "123--_"        #=> false (no letters) 
username_valid? "Melba1-23--_"  #=> false (3 hyphens)
username_valid? "Bob1_23_-$"    #=> false ($ not permitted)
```

[Hash#new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) with an argument (the default value) of zero is often called a *counting hash*. If `h` is a hash with no key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value. It is evaluated thusly:

```
h[k] += 1
  #=> h[k] = h[k] + 1
  #=> h[k] = 0 + 1
```

The method could instead be written to return `false` as soon as it determines that the regex is incorrect.

```
def username_valid?(username)
  cnt = username.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c,cnt|
    case c
    when /\d/
    when /[[:alpha:]]/
      cnt[:letter] += 1
    when '-'
      return false if cnt[:hyphen] == 2 
      cnt[:hyphen] += 1
    when '_'
      return false if cnt[:underscore] == 2 
      cnt[:underscore] += 1
    else
      return false
    end
  end
  cnt.fetch(:letter, 0) > 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad use for a regular expression because your data isn't structured enough. Instead, a small series of simple tests will tell you what you need to know:

```
def valid?(str)
  str[/[a-z]/i] && str.tr('^-_', '').size <= 2
end

%w(123hi123hi hi123hi).each do |username|
  username # => "123hi123hi", "hi123hi"
  valid?(username) # => true,         true
end
```

There is a loss of speed due to the use of the regular expression

```
/[a-z]/i
```

so instead

```
def valid?(str)
  str.downcase.tr('^a-z', '').size >= 0 && str.tr('^-_', '').size <= 2
end
```

could be used. The use of the regular expression is about 45% slower based on testing.

Breaking it down:

- `str[/[a-z]/i]` tests for a minimum of one character. Since there can be more than one this will suffice.
- `str.downcase.tr('^a-z', '').size` converts the characters to lowercase, then strips all non-letter characters, resulting in only letters remaining, then counts how many there are:

  ```
  '123hi123hi'.downcase # => "123hi123hi"
              .tr('^a-z', '') # => "hihi"
              .size # => 4

  'hi123hi'.downcase # => "hi123hi"
           .tr('^a-z', '') # => "hihi"
           .size # => 4

  'hi-123_hi'.downcase # => "hi-123_hi"
             .tr('^a-z', '') # => "hihi"
             .size # => 4
  ```

The rule

> May contain any amount of numbers, anywhere

isn't worth testing so I ignored it.

Answer (score -1):

This is improved version of that regex of yours

```
^[\w-]*[A-Za-z]+[\w-]*$
```

But this will fail to calculate how many - or _ there, so you will need another regex to filter that or count that manually on code.
This is the regex for check only two or less [-_] disregarding its position:

```
^[A-Za-z\d]*[-_]{0,1}[A-Za-z\d]*[-_]{0,1}[A-Za-z\d]*$
```

Comment: `^` means beginning of *line* in Ruby, not *string*; you almost always want to use `\A` instead. Similarly, `\z` instead of `$`.

Comment: But using `^` and `$` can allow usernames through that contain newlines, that's why you need to use the string-anchors (`\A` and `\z`) instead of line-anchors (`^` and `$`).

Comment: did you say that `^\w*$` match with two line of any word?

Comment: The OP's `check_username` method shows that a username may contain, say, two hyphens and one underscore. Your regex would not permit that.  Nor does it enforce the requirement that it must contain at least one letter. Note that `[-_]{0,1}` is the same as `[-_]{,1}` or, simpler, `[-_]?`.

Comment: what i catch is he say `count(hyphens or underscore)<=2` not `two hyphens and one underscore`. {0,1} is easier to read and modify, but i also know that `?` also work fine. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The method I mentioned contains `if self.username.count("-") > 2` and   `self.username.count("_") > 2` as separate requirements.

Comment: If that what @Riptyde4 want, then he better do the second step in code, or if insist using regex, he can repeat that second regex twice with change [-_] to only - and then _

Answer (score -1):

If you're allowing only letters, numbers, dashes and underscores,

and everything else is considered a special character,

I think it's only that the pattern you have needs negation.

Instead of `(self.username =~ /^[0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+$/) !=0`

try `(self.username =~ /^[^0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+$/) !=0`

or `(self.username =~ /^[\W-]+$/) > 0`.

Also, why not do a count for special characters, like in the conditions above this one?

Comment: `^` means beginning of *line* in Ruby, not *string*; you almost always want to use `\A` instead. Similarly, `\z` instead of `$`.

Comment: `^` inside brackets is a negation of the rest of the expression(s) inside these brackets. `[^A]` means "anything but a capital A"

Comment: Yes but you're also using a caret as an anchor.